# How to pass Spanned Data-type data using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, baseadapter, spanned

I am passing some data from one activity to another. All the data are passing alright but there one with data type Spanned which isnt working at all.
When I display it in the first Activity,it works but when I display it in the other activity,it doest even appear.

I took the data from json like this

```
public void parseJsonData(final String jsonString) {

    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

        for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            news news1 = new news();
            news1.setCategory("Spor");
            news1.setTitle(jObject.getString("title"));
            news1.setDate(jObject.getString("date"));
            news1.setContent(Html.fromHtml(jObject.getString("content")));//Here the data type of Content is Spanned
            news1.setShort_content(jObject.getString("short_content"));
            Sdatalist.add(news1);

        }

        if (dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

From my Adapter I sent the data like this

```
 myholder.myimageview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(mycontext, Detailews.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("category", mydatalist.get(position).getCategory());
                myIntent.putExtra("title", mydatalist.get(position).getTitle());
                myIntent.putExtra("date", mydatalist.get(position).getDate());
                myIntent.putExtra("cont", mydatalist.get(position).getContent());
                myIntent.putExtra("image", mydatalist.get(position).getImage());
                mycontext.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
```

And in the other activity I recieved the data like this

```
   cat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Dtextcategory);
    dat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Ddatetext);
    tit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Dtitletext);
    con = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    final  String image_url = in.getStringExtra("image");
    final  String title = in.getStringExtra("title");
    final  String date = in.getStringExtra("date");
    final  String co = in.getStringExtra("cont");//If I try making the datatype here spanned,it wont understand :)
    final  String category = in.getStringExtra("category");

    cat.setText(category);
    dat.setText(date);
    tit.setText(title);
    con.setText(co); //Here is where it does not show.

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Dimage);
    new CustomAdapter.DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(image_url);
```

I need some one to find the bug. :) help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getContent()` would need to return a `CharSequence`. Then, use `getCharSequenceExtra()`, not `getStringExtra()`, saving it to a `CharSequence` variable.

IOW, strings do not have spans. `CharSequence` objects have spans. When you convert a `CharSequence` to a string via `toString()`, you lose the spans.

Comment: Thank you very much. It woked. But is there a way of solving the problem of lossing the spans.

Comment: @A-Majeed: If you put a `CharSequence` into an extra that has spans, and you retrieve it via `getCharSequenceExtra()`, it should not lose the spans.

Comment: Okay. That was Excellent. Now I got it. I need to now make the textview scrollable in order to see the text below. Thank you once again.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I'm implementing your suggestion but getting a link-stripped version of the CharSequence on the other side here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016940